# How to combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 20 x 4000 dataframe in Python using pandas. Two of these columns are named Year and quarter. I'd like to create a variable called period that makes Year = 2000 and quarter= q2 into 2000q2.

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: `df['period'] = df['year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both columns are strings, you can concatenate them directly:

```
df["period"] = df["Year"] + df["quarter"]
```

If one (or both) of the columns are not string typed, you should convert it (them) first,

```
df["period"] = df["Year"].astype(str) + df["quarter"]
```

If you need to join multiple string columns, you can use agg:

```
df['period'] = df[['Year', 'quarter', ...]].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

Where "-" is the separator.